# How do I create an automated chrome browser script? (Refreshes page when text is displayed.)

Tags: google-chrome, macros, google-chrome-extensions, bots

I'm trying to create a bot for a game in the chrome browser that will automatically refresh the page when text is displayed, and also wait and refresh the page after other text is displayed...but I can't seem to figure it out.  What could I use to create a script like this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very far from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385500/search-document-innerhtml.  What I would do in the extension code:

1. Create a function to search for your test and refresh the page if the text is found.
2. Call this function when the page is printed for the first time (just in case).
3. Add an event listener for DOM changes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: This looks good.  Thank you!  Sorry I didn't see that link when I was searching.